# Android listview row delete animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

What is the best way to animate a listview row?

I keep trying something like:

```
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_up_fade_anim);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                dataSource.remove(index);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        view.startAnimation(animation);
```

but the animation isn't exactly what i want. I think i need to animate every other listview row except the deleted one, but i am open to suggestions.

Comment: did you try the below?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's the sourcee code (for android 4.1 i guess).

http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewRemovalAnimation.zip

Here's the link to the video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_XOgcRukSoKKjewFJZrKV0&v=YCHNAi9kJI4

Here's a blog Google Engineer

http://www.graphics-geek.blogspot.in.

You have the videos to get to know what's happening. You also get to know how to port back to previous versions.

Example:

ListViewRemovalAnimation.java

```
public class ListViewRemovalAnimation extends Activity {

    StableArrayAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mListView;
    BackgroundContainer mBackgroundContainer;
    boolean mSwiping = false;
    boolean mItemPressed = false;
    HashMap<Long, Integer> mItemIdTopMap = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

    private static final int SWIPE_DURATION = 250;
    private static final int MOVE_DURATION = 150;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_deletion);

        mBackgroundContainer = (BackgroundContainer) findViewById(R.id.listViewBackground);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        android.util.Log.d("Debug", "d=" + mListView.getDivider());
        final ArrayList<String> cheeseList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Cheeses.sCheeseStrings.length; ++i) {
            cheeseList.add(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings[i]);
        }
        mAdapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.opaque_text_view, cheeseList,
                mTouchListener);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Handle touch events to fade/move dragged items as they are swiped out
     */
    private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float mDownX;
        private int mSwipeSlop = -1;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (mSwipeSlop < 0) {
                mSwipeSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(ListViewRemovalAnimation.this).
                        getScaledTouchSlop();
            }
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mItemPressed) {
                    // Multi-item swipes not handled
                    return false;
                }
                mItemPressed = true;
                mDownX = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                v.setAlpha(1);
                v.setTranslationX(0);
                mItemPressed = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    float x = event.getX() + v.getTranslationX();
                    float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                    float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                    if (!mSwiping) {
                        if (deltaXAbs > mSwipeSlop) {
                            mSwiping = true;
                            mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            mBackgroundContainer.showBackground(v.getTop(), v.getHeight());
                        }
                    }
                    if (mSwiping) {
                        v.setTranslationX((x - mDownX));
                        v.setAlpha(1 - deltaXAbs / v.getWidth());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    // User let go - figure out whether to animate the view out, or back into place
                    if (mSwiping) {
                        float x = event.getX() + v.getTranslationX();
                        float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                        float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                        float fractionCovered;
                        float endX;
                        float endAlpha;
                        final boolean remove;
                        if (deltaXAbs > v.getWidth() / 4) {
                            // Greater than a quarter of the width - animate it out
                            fractionCovered = deltaXAbs / v.getWidth();
                            endX = deltaX < 0 ? -v.getWidth() : v.getWidth();
                            endAlpha = 0;
                            remove = true;
                        } else {
                            // Not far enough - animate it back
                            fractionCovered = 1 - (deltaXAbs / v.getWidth());
                            endX = 0;
                            endAlpha = 1;
                            remove = false;
                        }
                        // Animate position and alpha of swiped item
                        // NOTE: This is a simplified version of swipe behavior, for the
                        // purposes of this demo about animation. A real version should use
                        // velocity (via the VelocityTracker class) to send the item off or
                        // back at an appropriate speed.
                        long duration = (int) ((1 - fractionCovered) * SWIPE_DURATION);
                        mListView.setEnabled(false);
                        v.animate().setDuration(duration).
                                alpha(endAlpha).translationX(endX).
                                withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // Restore animated values
                                        v.setAlpha(1);
                                        v.setTranslationX(0);
                                        if (remove) {
                                            animateRemoval(mListView, v);
                                        } else {
                                            mBackgroundContainer.hideBackground();
                                            mSwiping = false;
                                            mListView.setEnabled(true);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
                mItemPressed = false;
                break;
            default: 
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * This method animates all other views in the ListView container (not including ignoreView)
     * into their final positions. It is called after ignoreView has been removed from the
     * adapter, but before layout has been run. The approach here is to figure out where
     * everything is now, then allow layout to run, then figure out where everything is after
     * layout, and then to run animations between all of those start/end positions.
     */
    private void animateRemoval(final ListView listview, View viewToRemove) {
        int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View child = listview.getChildAt(i);
            if (child != viewToRemove) {
                int position = firstVisiblePosition + i;
                long itemId = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
                mItemIdTopMap.put(itemId, child.getTop());
            }
        }
        // Delete the item from the adapter
        int position = mListView.getPositionForView(viewToRemove);
        mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));

        final ViewTreeObserver observer = listview.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                boolean firstAnimation = true;
                int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                    final View child = listview.getChildAt(i);
                    int position = firstVisiblePosition + i;
                    long itemId = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
                    Integer startTop = mItemIdTopMap.get(itemId);
                    int top = child.getTop();
                    if (startTop != null) {
                        if (startTop != top) {
                            int delta = startTop - top;
                            child.setTranslationY(delta);
                            child.animate().setDuration(MOVE_DURATION).translationY(0);
                            if (firstAnimation) {
                                child.animate().withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        mBackgroundContainer.hideBackground();
                                        mSwiping = false;
                                        mListView.setEnabled(true);
                                    }
                                });
                                firstAnimation = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Animate new views along with the others. The catch is that they did not
                        // exist in the start state, so we must calculate their starting position
                        // based on neighboring views.
                        int childHeight = child.getHeight() + listview.getDividerHeight();
                        startTop = top + (i > 0 ? childHeight : -childHeight);
                        int delta = startTop - top;
                        child.setTranslationY(delta);
                        child.animate().setDuration(MOVE_DURATION).translationY(0);
                        if (firstAnimation) {
                            child.animate().withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    mBackgroundContainer.hideBackground();
                                    mSwiping = false;
                                    mListView.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            });
                            firstAnimation = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                mItemIdTopMap.clear();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

StableArrayAdapter.java

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener;

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects, View.OnTouchListener listener) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mTouchListener = listener;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (view != convertView) {
            // Add touch listener to every new view to track swipe motion
            view.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

Cheese.java

```
public class Cheeses {

    public static final String[] sCheeseStrings = {
            "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
            "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale",
            "Aisy Cendre", "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Alverca", "Ambert", "American Cheese",
            "Ami du Chambertin", "Anejo Enchilado", "Anneau du Vic-Bilh", "Anthoriro", "Appenzell",
            "Aragon", "Ardi Gasna", "Ardrahan", "Armenian String", "Aromes au Gene de Marc",
            "Asadero", "Asiago", "Aubisque Pyrenees", "Autun", "Avaxtskyr", "Baby Swiss",
            "Babybel", "Baguette Laonnaise", "Bakers", "Baladi", "Balaton", "Bandal", "Banon",
            "Barry's Bay Cheddar", "Basing", "Basket Cheese", "Bath Cheese", "Bavarian Bergkase",
            "Baylough", "Beaufort", "Beauvoorde", "Beenleigh Blue", "Beer Cheese", "Bel Paese",
            "Bergader", "Bergere Bleue", "Berkswell", "Beyaz Peynir", "Bierkase", "Bishop Kennedy",
            "Blarney", "Bleu d'Auvergne", "Bleu de Gex", "Bleu de Laqueuille",
            "Bleu de Septmoncel", "Bleu Des Causses", "Blue", "Blue Castello", "Blue Rathgore",
            "Blue Vein (Australian)", "Blue Vein Cheeses", "Bocconcini", "Bocconcini (Australian)",
            "Boeren Leidenkaas", "Bonchester", "Bosworth", "Bougon", "Boule Du Roves",
            "Boulette d'Avesnes", "Boursault", "Boursin", "Bouyssou", "Bra", "Braudostur",
            "Breakfast Cheese", "Brebis du Lavort", "Brebis du Lochois", "Brebis du Puyfaucon",
            "Bresse Bleu", "Brick", "Brie", "Brie de Meaux", "Brie de Melun", "Brillat-Savarin",
            "Brin", "Brin d' Amour", "Brin d'Amour", "Brinza (Burduf Brinza)",
            "Briquette de Brebis", "Briquette du Forez", "Broccio", "Broccio Demi-Affine",
            "Brousse du Rove", "Bruder Basil", "Brusselae Kaas (Fromage de Bruxelles)", "Bryndza",
            "Buchette d'Anjou", "Buffalo", "Burgos", "Butte", "Butterkase", "Button (Innes)",
            "Buxton Blue", "Cabecou", "Caboc", "Cabrales", "Cachaille", "Caciocavallo", "Caciotta",
            "Caerphilly", "Cairnsmore", "Calenzana", "Cambazola", "Camembert de Normandie",
            "Canadian Cheddar", "Canestrato", "Cantal", "Caprice des Dieux", "Capricorn Goat",
            "Capriole Banon", "Carre de l'Est", "Casciotta di Urbino", "Cashel Blue", "Castellano",
            "Castelleno", "Castelmagno", "Castelo Branco", "Castigliano", "Cathelain",
            "Celtic Promise", "Cendre d'Olivet", "Cerney", "Chabichou", "Chabichou du Poitou",
            "Chabis de Gatine", "Chaource", "Charolais", "Chaumes", "Cheddar",
            "Cheddar Clothbound", "Cheshire", "Chevres", "Chevrotin des Aravis", "Chontaleno",
            "Civray", "Coeur de Camembert au Calvados", "Coeur de Chevre", "Colby", "Cold Pack",
            "Comte", "Coolea", "Cooleney", "Coquetdale", "Corleggy", "Cornish Pepper",
            "Cotherstone", "Cotija", "Cottage Cheese", "Cottage Cheese (Australian)",
            "Cougar Gold", "Coulommiers", "Coverdale", "Crayeux de Roncq", "Cream Cheese",
            "Cream Havarti", "Crema Agria", "Crema Mexicana", "Creme Fraiche", "Crescenza",
            "Croghan", "Crottin de Chavignol", "Crottin du Chavignol", "Crowdie", "Crowley",
            "Cuajada", "Curd", "Cure Nantais", "Curworthy", "Cwmtawe Pecorino",
            "Cypress Grove Chevre", "Danablu (Danish Blue)", "Danbo", "Danish Fontina",
            "Daralagjazsky", "Dauphin", "Delice des Fiouves", "Denhany Dorset Drum", "Derby",
            "Dessertnyj Belyj", "Devon Blue", "Devon Garland", "Dolcelatte", "Doolin",
            "Doppelrhamstufel", "Dorset Blue Vinney", "Double Gloucester", "Double Worcester",
            "Dreux a la Feuille", "Dry Jack", "Duddleswell", "Dunbarra", "Dunlop", "Dunsyre Blue",
            "Duroblando", "Durrus", "Dutch Mimolette (Commissiekaas)", "Edam", "Edelpilz",
            "Emental Grand Cru", "Emlett", "Emmental", "Epoisses de Bourgogne", "Esbareich",
            "Esrom", "Etorki", "Evansdale Farmhouse Brie", "Evora De L'Alentejo", "Exmoor Blue",
            "Explorateur", "Feta", "Feta (Australian)", "Figue", "Filetta", "Fin-de-Siecle",
            "Finlandia Swiss", "Finn", "Fiore Sardo", "Fleur du Maquis", "Flor de Guia",
            "Flower Marie", "Folded", "Folded cheese with mint", "Fondant de Brebis",
            "Fontainebleau", "Fontal", "Fontina Val d'Aosta", "Formaggio di capra", "Fougerus",
            "Four Herb Gouda", "Fourme d' Ambert", "Fourme de Haute Loire", "Fourme de Montbrison",
            "Fresh Jack", "Fresh Mozzarella", "Fresh Ricotta", "Fresh Truffles", "Fribourgeois",
            "Friesekaas", "Friesian", "Friesla", "Frinault", "Fromage a Raclette", "Fromage Corse",
            "Fromage de Montagne de Savoie", "Fromage Frais", "Fruit Cream Cheese",
            "Frying Cheese", "Fynbo", "Gabriel", "Galette du Paludier", "Galette Lyonnaise",
            "Galloway Goat's Milk Gems", "Gammelost", "Gaperon a l'Ail", "Garrotxa", "Gastanberra",
            "Geitost", "Gippsland Blue", "Gjetost", "Gloucester", "Golden Cross", "Gorgonzola",
            "Gornyaltajski", "Gospel Green", "Gouda", "Goutu", "Gowrie", "Grabetto", "Graddost",
            "Grafton Village Cheddar", "Grana", "Grana Padano", "Grand Vatel",
            "Grataron d' Areches", "Gratte-Paille", "Graviera", "Greuilh", "Greve",
            "Gris de Lille", "Gruyere", "Gubbeen", "Guerbigny", "Halloumi",
            "Halloumy (Australian)", "Haloumi-Style Cheese", "Harbourne Blue", "Havarti",
            "Heidi Gruyere", "Hereford Hop", "Herrgardsost", "Herriot Farmhouse", "Herve",
            "Hipi Iti", "Hubbardston Blue Cow", "Hushallsost", "Iberico", "Idaho Goatster",
            "Idiazabal", "Il Boschetto al Tartufo", "Ile d'Yeu", "Isle of Mull", "Jarlsberg",
            "Jermi Tortes", "Jibneh Arabieh", "Jindi Brie", "Jubilee Blue", "Juustoleipa",
            "Kadchgall", "Kaseri", "Kashta", "Kefalotyri", "Kenafa", "Kernhem", "Kervella Affine",
            "Kikorangi", "King Island Cape Wickham Brie", "King River Gold", "Klosterkaese",
            "Knockalara", "Kugelkase", "L'Aveyronnais", "L'Ecir de l'Aubrac", "La Taupiniere",
            "La Vache Qui Rit", "Laguiole", "Lairobell", "Lajta", "Lanark Blue", "Lancashire",
            "Langres", "Lappi", "Laruns", "Lavistown", "Le Brin", "Le Fium Orbo", "Le Lacandou",
            "Le Roule", "Leafield", "Lebbene", "Leerdammer", "Leicester", "Leyden", "Limburger",
            "Lincolnshire Poacher", "Lingot Saint Bousquet d'Orb", "Liptauer", "Little Rydings",
            "Livarot", "Llanboidy", "Llanglofan Farmhouse", "Loch Arthur Farmhouse",
            "Loddiswell Avondale", "Longhorn", "Lou Palou", "Lou Pevre", "Lyonnais", "Maasdam",
            "Macconais", "Mahoe Aged Gouda", "Mahon", "Malvern", "Mamirolle", "Manchego",
            "Manouri", "Manur", "Marble Cheddar", "Marbled Cheeses", "Maredsous", "Margotin",
            "Maribo", "Maroilles", "Mascares", "Mascarpone", "Mascarpone (Australian)",
            "Mascarpone Torta", "Matocq", "Maytag Blue", "Meira", "Menallack Farmhouse",
            "Menonita", "Meredith Blue", "Mesost", "Metton (Cancoillotte)", "Meyer Vintage Gouda",
            "Mihalic Peynir", "Milleens", "Mimolette", "Mine-Gabhar", "Mini Baby Bells", "Mixte",
            "Molbo", "Monastery Cheeses", "Mondseer", "Mont D'or Lyonnais", "Montasio",
            "Monterey Jack", "Monterey Jack Dry", "Morbier", "Morbier Cru de Montagne",
            "Mothais a la Feuille", "Mozzarella", "Mozzarella (Australian)",
            "Mozzarella di Bufala", "Mozzarella Fresh, in water", "Mozzarella Rolls", "Munster",
            "Murol", "Mycella", "Myzithra", "Naboulsi", "Nantais", "Neufchatel",
            "Neufchatel (Australian)", "Niolo", "Nokkelost", "Northumberland", "Oaxaca",
            "Olde York", "Olivet au Foin", "Olivet Bleu", "Olivet Cendre",
            "Orkney Extra Mature Cheddar", "Orla", "Oschtjepka", "Ossau Fermier", "Ossau-Iraty",
            "Oszczypek", "Oxford Blue", "P'tit Berrichon", "Palet de Babligny", "Paneer", "Panela",
            "Pannerone", "Pant ys Gawn", "Parmesan (Parmigiano)", "Parmigiano Reggiano",
            "Pas de l'Escalette", "Passendale", "Pasteurized Processed", "Pate de Fromage",
            "Patefine Fort", "Pave d'Affinois", "Pave d'Auge", "Pave de Chirac", "Pave du Berry",
            "Pecorino", "Pecorino in Walnut Leaves", "Pecorino Romano", "Peekskill Pyramid",
            "Pelardon des Cevennes", "Pelardon des Corbieres", "Penamellera", "Penbryn",
            "Pencarreg", "Perail de Brebis", "Petit Morin", "Petit Pardou", "Petit-Suisse",
            "Picodon de Chevre", "Picos de Europa", "Piora", "Pithtviers au Foin",
            "Plateau de Herve", "Plymouth Cheese", "Podhalanski", "Poivre d'Ane", "Polkolbin",
            "Pont l'Eveque", "Port Nicholson", "Port-Salut", "Postel", "Pouligny-Saint-Pierre",
            "Pourly", "Prastost", "Pressato", "Prince-Jean", "Processed Cheddar", "Provolone",
            "Provolone (Australian)", "Pyengana Cheddar", "Pyramide", "Quark",
            "Quark (Australian)", "Quartirolo Lombardo", "Quatre-Vents", "Quercy Petit",
            "Queso Blanco", "Queso Blanco con Frutas --Pina y Mango", "Queso de Murcia",
            "Queso del Montsec", "Queso del Tietar", "Queso Fresco", "Queso Fresco (Adobera)",
            "Queso Iberico", "Queso Jalapeno", "Queso Majorero", "Queso Media Luna",
            "Queso Para Frier", "Queso Quesadilla", "Rabacal", "Raclette", "Ragusano", "Raschera",
            "Reblochon", "Red Leicester", "Regal de la Dombes", "Reggianito", "Remedou",
            "Requeson", "Richelieu", "Ricotta", "Ricotta (Australian)", "Ricotta Salata", "Ridder",
            "Rigotte", "Rocamadour", "Rollot", "Romano", "Romans Part Dieu", "Roncal", "Roquefort",
            "Roule", "Rouleau De Beaulieu", "Royalp Tilsit", "Rubens", "Rustinu", "Saaland Pfarr",
            "Saanenkaese", "Saga", "Sage Derby", "Sainte Maure", "Saint-Marcellin",
            "Saint-Nectaire", "Saint-Paulin", "Salers", "Samso", "San Simon", "Sancerre",
            "Sap Sago", "Sardo", "Sardo Egyptian", "Sbrinz", "Scamorza", "Schabzieger", "Schloss",
            "Selles sur Cher", "Selva", "Serat", "Seriously Strong Cheddar", "Serra da Estrela",
            "Sharpam", "Shelburne Cheddar", "Shropshire Blue", "Siraz", "Sirene", "Smoked Gouda",
            "Somerset Brie", "Sonoma Jack", "Sottocenare al Tartufo", "Soumaintrain",
            "Sourire Lozerien", "Spenwood", "Sraffordshire Organic", "St. Agur Blue Cheese",
            "Stilton", "Stinking Bishop", "String", "Sussex Slipcote", "Sveciaost", "Swaledale",
            "Sweet Style Swiss", "Swiss", "Syrian (Armenian String)", "Tala", "Taleggio", "Tamie",
            "Tasmania Highland Chevre Log", "Taupiniere", "Teifi", "Telemea", "Testouri",
            "Tete de Moine", "Tetilla", "Texas Goat Cheese", "Tibet", "Tillamook Cheddar",
            "Tilsit", "Timboon Brie", "Toma", "Tomme Brulee", "Tomme d'Abondance",
            "Tomme de Chevre", "Tomme de Romans", "Tomme de Savoie", "Tomme des Chouans", "Tommes",
            "Torta del Casar", "Toscanello", "Touree de L'Aubier", "Tourmalet",
            "Trappe (Veritable)", "Trois Cornes De Vendee", "Tronchon", "Trou du Cru", "Truffe",
            "Tupi", "Turunmaa", "Tymsboro", "Tyn Grug", "Tyning", "Ubriaco", "Ulloa",
            "Vacherin-Fribourgeois", "Valencay", "Vasterbottenost", "Venaco", "Vendomois",
            "Vieux Corse", "Vignotte", "Vulscombe", "Waimata Farmhouse Blue",
            "Washed Rind Cheese (Australian)", "Waterloo", "Weichkaese", "Wellington",
            "Wensleydale", "White Stilton", "Whitestone Farmhouse", "Wigmore", "Woodside Cabecou",
            "Xanadu", "Xynotyro", "Yarg Cornish", "Yarra Valley Pyramid", "Yorkshire Blue",
            "Zamorano", "Zanetti Grana Padano", "Zanetti Parmigiano Reggiano"
    };

}
```

BackgroundContainer.java

```
public class BackgroundContainer extends FrameLayout {

    boolean mShowing = false;
    Drawable mShadowedBackground;
    int mOpenAreaTop, mOpenAreaBottom, mOpenAreaHeight;
    boolean mUpdateBounds = false;

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mShadowedBackground =
                getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadowed_background);
    }

    public void showBackground(int top, int bottom) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mOpenAreaTop = top;
        mOpenAreaHeight = bottom;
        mShowing = true;
        mUpdateBounds = true;
    }

    public void hideBackground() {
        setWillNotDraw(true);
        mShowing = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mShowing) {
                if (mUpdateBounds) {
                mShadowedBackground.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), mOpenAreaHeight);
                }
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(0, mOpenAreaTop);
            mShadowedBackground.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

}
```

Layout files

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListViewAnimations" >

    <view
        class="com.example.android.listviewremovalanimation.BackgroundContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewBackground">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </view>

</LinearLayout>
```

opaque_text_view.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tv_background_with_divider"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

Comment: This works great, but I need something that works earlier than android 4.1.

Comment: @VladManolache http://www.graphics-geek.blogspot.in. This is link has everything even porting back to previous versions. There is topic on animating listview deletion on Gingerbread.

Comment: Awesome, it works. I saw the article, but I guess I just needed a little confidence to get it working. Thanks again.

Comment: hey @Raghunandan i think they deleted the zip file......the code which you have provided here ..is it the same??

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava no they have not you need to check the older posts on the blog.

Comment: I am sorry u didn't get me,what i meant was it was not working earlier for me because of some idm(internet download manager) problem....but when i tried manually it worked fine...

Comment: What about Multi-item swipes handle..??

Comment: @AbhishekPatel you can swipe multiple items in the list. I din't understand your comment

Comment: yes.@Raghunandan .how to swipe multiple item swipe in single listview,not one by one...

Comment: @AbhishekPatel you will have to go through the code and implement it yourself. Multiple row swipes at the same time! this could be complex.

Comment: Did anybody have a problem with wrong items being deleted? When I swipe let's say 5th item of 10, it deletes it (animation goes for that item) BUT it actually deletes the LAST item, and just shifts them all up by one position.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my initial attempt at encapsulating everything if anybody else needed this.

Usage:

```
ListViewAnimationHelper helper = new ListViewAnimationHelper(adapter, listView, dataSource);
helper.animateRemoval(listView, lastSelectedView);
```

Code:

```
package com.android.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.android.objects.FoodItem;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener; 
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListViewAnimationHelper {

    BaseAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView; 
    ArrayList<FoodItem> dataSource;
    HashMap<Long, Integer> mItemIdTopMap = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
    private static final int MOVE_DURATION = 150;

// ================================================================================ 
// Constructor
// ================================================================================ 

    public ListViewAnimationHelper(BaseAdapter adapter, ListView listView, ArrayList<FoodItem>dataSource) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.listView = listView;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

// ================================================================================ 
// ListView row animation helper
// ================================================================================ 

    /**
     * This method animates all other views in the ListView container (not including ignoreView)
     * into their final positions. It is called after ignoreView has been removed from the
     * adapter, but before layout has been run. The approach here is to figure out where
     * everything is now, then allow layout to run, then figure out where everything is after
     * layout, and then to run animations between all of those start/end positions.
     */

    public void animateRemoval(final ListView listview, View viewToRemove) {
        int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View child = listview.getChildAt(i);
            if (child != viewToRemove) {
                int position = firstVisiblePosition + i;
                long itemId = adapter.getItemId(position);
                mItemIdTopMap.put(itemId, child.getTop());
            }
        }
        // Delete the item from the adapter 
        int position = listView.getPositionForView(viewToRemove); 
        dataSource.remove (position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        final ViewTreeObserver observer = listview.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                boolean firstAnimation = true;
                int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                    final View child = listview.getChildAt(i);
                    int position = firstVisiblePosition + i;
                    long itemId = adapter.getItemId(position);
                    Integer startTop = mItemIdTopMap.get(itemId);
                    int top = child.getTop();
                    if (startTop == null) {
                        // Animate new views along with the others. The catch is that they did not
                        // exist in the start state, so we must calculate their starting position
                        // based on whether they're coming in from the bottom (i > 0) or top.
                        int childHeight = child.getHeight() + listview.getDividerHeight();
                        startTop = top + (i > 0 ? childHeight : -childHeight);
                    }
                    int delta = startTop - top;
                    if (delta != 0) {
                        Runnable endAction = firstAnimation ?
                                new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {   
                                listView.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        } : null;
                        firstAnimation = false;
                        moveView(child, 0, 0, delta, 0, endAction);
                    }
                }
                mItemIdTopMap.clear();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

// ================================================================================ 
// Interface declaration
// ================================================================================ 

    /**
     * Utility, to avoid having to implement every method in AnimationListener in
     * every implementation class
     */
    static class AnimationListenerAdapter implements AnimationListener {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
    }

// ================================================================================ 
// Honeycomb support
// ================================================================================ 

    /**
     * Returns true if the current runtime is Honeycomb or later
     */
    private boolean isRuntimePostGingerbread() {
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    }

    /**
     * Animate a view between start and end X/Y locations, using either old (pre-3.0) or
     * new animation APIs.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void moveView(View view, float startX, float endX, float startY, float endY, Runnable endAction) {
        final Runnable finalEndAction = endAction;
        if (isRuntimePostGingerbread()) {
            view.animate().setDuration(MOVE_DURATION);
            if (startX != endX) {
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_X, startX, endX);
                anim.setDuration(MOVE_DURATION);
                anim.start();
                setAnimatorEndAction(anim, endAction);
                endAction = null;
            }
            if (startY != endY) {
                ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_Y, startY, endY);
                anim.setDuration(MOVE_DURATION);
                anim.start();
                setAnimatorEndAction(anim, endAction);
            }
        } else {
            TranslateAnimation translator = new TranslateAnimation(startX, endX, startY, endY);
            translator.setDuration(MOVE_DURATION);
            view.startAnimation(translator);
            if (endAction != null) {
                view.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new AnimationListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        finalEndAction.run();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setAnimatorEndAction(Animator animator, final Runnable endAction) {
        if (endAction != null) {
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    endAction.run();
                }
            });
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: This works really well and makes it easy to extend to doing things like animating list item movement.

Comment: Some apis here are only available post icecreamsandwich, so i dont understand which the check is for gingerbread...

Comment: i know this one is too old but what do i pass in `helper.animateRemoval(listView, lastSelectedView);`, how to get the lastSelectedView?