# How to replace the new item in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I searched StackOverflow but I didn't find any opted solution. I have `ListView`, and I want to `delete(like swipe the listview item)` the `listviewitem` and `replace with new image or show new image  at that deleted position` in ListView, how to do that? any can help to solve this....

i have try this one

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) lView.getChildAt(position);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.redo);
```

but not posiible to get result!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this following github project.

You can find exactly what you asked for at there are lots of options available with this one you can find undo in two buttons like swipe to dismiss and animate dismiss..

The undo options are present at the action bar. Undo also available for time based..

[ListViewAnimationWithRedo source](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)

the google play live demo available here...

[The working demo of listview redo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations)

Answer (score 2):

You can check this blog by Chat Hasse

http://graphics-geek.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2013-06-28T10:23:00-07:00&max-results=7

There is explanation and the code to port for lower versions also. The example shows you how to swipe and delete a listitem with text.

For an example check my answer @

[Android listview row delete animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation/17858152#17858152)

Maintain a list of drawables. Delete the drawable from the list according to swiped postion in the listview. Refresh your list by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it satisfies to remove the listitem but in that position i want to show the redo button or image how to do that....

Comment: @Arut the item move up it does not replace. i am not aware of how to do that. If you want to replace then what is the need for deletion. just use the position and replace the image.

Comment: Thank for your reply....replace for redo...i will try to replce...your answer is upvoted once i done the replace in that position i will accept...

Answer (score 0):

you have to refresh the adapter. Try this:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i want to remove the item and then display the redo image this is my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to recreate your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged().

```
myadapter=new myListViewAdapter(....);
myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i want to remove the item at particular position and then display the redo image that removed position this is my expectation.

Comment: as i know you can't remove specific item from listview directly but you can modify your adapter whit new data and then refresh you'r listview whit notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: i am able to remove listitem with help of animation.

Answer (score 0):

I Expect that you r maintaining database to insert and delete the images...if u r so...
then by using cursor in database you can fetch all the values of a column in a method and call the method immediately after deleting or inserting the images

Comment: i want to remove the item at particular position and then display the redo image that removed position this is my expectation.

Comment: you can refer this https://www.timroes.de/2013/06/15/swipetodismiss-undo/...http://blog.erayince.com.tr/?p=194 they are not using DB...