# Listview Re-alignment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created a listview. On Swipe on the listview a button will be displayed which is used for deleting the list. but if i press cancel the list stays expaned. I want the list to re-align the list to its original position.
I have attached the screenshots.

initially the listview shows like this

[image]

after swiping

[image]

after pressing cancel button in the alert

[image]

Comment: you can swipe and delete the row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation. check this and modify according to your needs

Comment: i am able to delete the row. No problems with that. In case i don't want to delete then the delete and press cancel button to the alert that rises up, it leaves a space like above.

Comment: How do you add/remove the button?

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted code so it difficult to judge what could be cause but you can try to invalidate the view of that particular row for which you showing and hiding the delete button. Also for hiding the delete button try setting yourDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your custom `ListView` item with the delete button with visibility `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`.
2. Register your `ListView` to `onTouch` event with [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) :

   mList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             
       return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
   });
   ```

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

1. Use `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` onFling:

   public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

   ```
               int dx = (int)(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
               int dy = (int)(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

               int pos = mList.pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY());
               Log.i("Fling", "Fling  " + dx + "  pos: " + pos);

               if ((Math.abs(dx) >= FLING_X_TRESHOLD) && (Math.abs(dy) < FLING_Y_TRESHOLD)) {
                   if(dx > 0){ //RTL - show
                       mAdapter.showDeleteButton(pos);
                   }else{
                       mAdapter.hideDeleteButton(pos);
                   }
               }

           return false;
       }
   ```
2. Inside your adapter create methods for show and hide the delete. To refresh the views use `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`