# Drag to Delete from a list in android

Tags: android, list, draggable

I want something like the list of items in `Gmail` on mobile.

There, when we drag an item horizontally the item disappears and some other things happen.

I want to know how to do something like this in my list of objects.

Comment: swipe to delete row item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation

Comment: thanks ... anything is ok now .

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code to delete row item with the help of swipe.....

```
public void delete_operation() {
        list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture_detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }

 GestureDetector gesture_detector = new GestureDetector(
                new OnGestureListener() {
                    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
                    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                        boolean result = false;
                        try {
                            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                                    if (diffX > 0) {

                                        onSwipeRight();
                                    } else {
                                        row_id_ins = lst_pollution.pointToPosition(
                                                (int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY());
                                        Log.e("", "id.......row" + row_id_ins);
                                        id_ins = row_id_ins + 1;
                                        row_id_str = String.valueOf(id_ins);
                                        Log.d("", "ROW ID" + row_id_str);
                                        onSwipeLeft();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {

                            }
                        } catch (Exception exception) {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return result;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        final class gesture_detector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Log.e("", "onSwipeRight");
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            Log.e("", "onSwipeRight");




        }

    }
```