# Android widget listview swipe to remove item

Tags: android, listview, widget, swipe

I have a widget with listview and I would like to make so that on swipe deletes list items, the complexity is that the widget has no direct link to the listview.
Do suggestions how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation. check this.

Comment: Look into this [github project](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss)

Comment: there for activity and listview, I have only widget.

Comment: Are you talking about homescreen widgets ? I'm curious to know how you think the system will differentiate the horizontal swipes to delete list items from the swipes to switch screen (also horizontal) ...

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about homescreen widgets.