# Android Listview remove item swipe with animation

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe, swipe-gesture

I would like to make dismiss animation when I remove item by swipe gesture from ListView
To remove item i use 
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout 
to support swipe gesture but in final I would like get animation like this http://img.gawkerassets.com/post/4/2013/02/mailbox-gif.gif

Comment: use animation on this list view https://github.com/ErNaveen/SwipeToDismissListviewItem

Comment: If you already tried to implement something for the animation then please include the relevant code in your post.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation) example