# how we delete the row in listview by using swipe in android

Tags: android

we are used the ListView in android.I want to delete the row in ListView by using swipe the row in android .but I don't know about this topic.Please somebody Help Me.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation

Answer (score 0):

**SwipeListView.java**

```
public class SwipeListView {
    MotionEvent last_motion;

    public static interface SwipeListViewCallback {


        public abstract ListView getListView();

        /**
         * 
         * @param isRight
         *            Swiping direction
         * @param position
         *            which item position is swiped
         */
        public abstract void onSwipeItem(boolean isRight, int position);

        /**
         * For single tap/Click
         * 
         * @param adapter
         * @param position
         */
        public abstract void onItemClickListener(ListAdapter adapter,
                int position);
    }

    Context m_Context;
    ListView mListView;
    SwipeListViewCallback m_Callback;

    public SwipeListView(Context mContext, SwipeListViewCallback callback) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        if (callback == null) {
            //
            try {
                throw new Exception(
                        "Activity must be implement SwipeListViewCallback");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        init(mContext, callback);
    }

    public SwipeListView(Context mContext) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        if (!(mContext instanceof SwipeListViewCallback)) {
            //
            throw new Exception(
                    "Activity must be implement SwipeListViewCallback");
        }
        init(mContext, (SwipeListViewCallback) mContext);
    }

    private ListView list;
    private int REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE;
    private int REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH;
    private int REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;

    protected void init(Context mContext, SwipeListViewCallback mCallback) {
        m_Context = mContext;
        m_Callback = mCallback;
    }

    public void exec() {
        //
        DisplayMetrics dm = m_Context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = (int) (100.0f * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f + 0.5);
        REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = (int) (250.0f * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f + 0.5);
        REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = (int) (100.0f * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f + 0.5);
        //
        list = m_Callback.getListView();

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(m_Context,
                new MyGestureDetector());

        View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };

        list.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

        // list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        //
        // @Override
        // public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // }
        // });
    }

    private void myOnItemClick(int position) {
        if (position < 0)
            return;
        m_Callback.onItemClickListener(list.getAdapter(), position);

    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private int temp_position = -1;

        /*
         * @Override public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
         * float distanceX, float distanceY) { // TODO Auto-generated method
         * stub
         * 
         * 
         * super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY); return false; }
         */

        // Detect a single-click and call my own handler.
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

            int pos = list.pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
            myOnItemClick(pos);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            temp_position = list
                    .pointToPosition((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
            // return super.onDown(e);
            last_motion = e;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            if (e1 == null || e2 == null) {
                if (last_motion != null) {
                    e1 = last_motion;
                }
            }

            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;

            if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                int pos = list
                        .pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e2.getY());

                if (pos >= 0 && temp_position == pos) {
                    m_Callback.onSwipeItem(true, pos);
                }
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() < REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                int pos = list
                        .pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e2.getY());
                if (pos >= 0 && temp_position == pos)
                    m_Callback.onSwipeItem(false, pos);
            }

            /*
             * else if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH
             * && Math.abs(velocityY) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
             * System.out.println("upward down"); } else if (Math.abs(e2.getY()
             * - e1.getY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(velocityY) >
             * REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
             * System.out.println("upward down"); }
             */

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
friendlistadapter = new FriendListAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.friends_list_item, listdata);
    lv_friendlistview.setAdapter(friendlistadapter);
    SwipeListView swipeListView = new SwipeListView(getActivity(), this);
    swipeListView.exec();
```

**FriendListadapter.java**

in adapter class

```
public void onSwipeItem(boolean isRight, int position) {

        if (isRight == false) {
            DELETE_POS = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if (DELETE_POS == position) {
            DELETE_POS = INVALID;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

In onCreateView method of adapter class to write beloved code.

```
    if (DELETE_POS == position) 
     {
        friendholder.iv_fr_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        friendholder.iv_fr_delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    friendholder.iv_fr_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listdata.remove(position);
                    friendholder.iv_fr_delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    DELETE_POS = INVALID;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```